# Dynamically replace checkboxlist display text

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

Could someone help me if there is any way to dynamically change the text of a checkboxlist control
display text without removing the checkbox icon.
I got the following HTML code:

```
<div class="classname1">
<div class="row checkbox-list list-container">
<label for="Example_Id">
<input type="checkbox" name="Example.Id" id="Example_Id" value="3"> Replace this text.
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to change this entire text. Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: where's your selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- Wrap the text inside a `span`
- Search for the `label` of the `input` using `input.labels` array
- Then, use `label.querySelector('span')` to get the `span` element
- Update the `span` text using `span.textContent = ...`

```js
const span = window.Example_Id.labels[0].querySelector("span");

span.textContent = value;
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-brown-w6so1r?file=/src/index.js:94-186